# How can the IE 11 scrollbar width be changed?

Tags: html, css, forms, frontend

First of all i apologize for my low English

I want to change the scrollbar width in IE browser

Thank you!

Comment: In the title, you mention specifically version 11 of IE. In the description, you mention "IE browser" without specifying a version number. Are you only interested in IE 11?

Comment: Please show what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research. Stack Overflow has a rich history of questions that cover several versions of Internet Explorer. Searching would be a good first step, as outlined in [ask].

Answer (score -1):

First of all... why you using IE? IE is out of date.
Now to your question. In webkit browsers like chrome you can use css to edit the scrollbar.
IE is not an webkit browser but you can do it with js.
[jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/) and [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) are jquery plugins for custom scrollbars.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what was said in the answer to the duplicate posted in my last comment. Please be on the look out for comments on questions with the phrase "Does this answer your question?" and click on the link. If the linked question is the same as the current question, and the answers answer it, there is no need to add another answer. Thanks. And good point about IE :).